# Dynamic Length Form handling and Data Collection in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a form in which the number of input fields keeps changing and depends on a parameter that I pass. This means that I can't go to forms.py and create a `Form` class because that requires me to define the input parameters beforehand.

Here is how I am defining the form.

```py
<!-- Table to Display the original sentence and take the input of the translation -->
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Original Sentence</th>
            <th scope="col">Translation</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <form name="translated-text-form" class="form-control" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <tbody>

                {% for sentence in sentences %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                    <td>{{ sentence.original_sentence }}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="translated-{{sentence.id}}" value="{{ sentence.translated_sentence }}" /></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <br>
                        <p style="text-align: center;">
                            <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" value="Save Translations"/>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </form>
      </table>
```

This is the form output
[image]

The user will add some text in the rightmost column and I want to save that text with a particular `sentence.id` in my `Sentence` model. This is what my model looks like

```py
class Sentence(models.Model): 
    """ Model which holds the details of a sentence. A sentence is a part of a Wikipedia article which is tokenized.

    Fields:
        project_id: The ID of the project to which the sentence belongs 
        original_sentence: The original sentence tokenized from from the Wikipedia article.
        translated_sentence: The translated sentence in the target language.
    """

    # Define the sentence model fields 
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    original_sentence = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    translated_sentence = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default="No Translation Found")
```

I know how I will approach this. In my `views.py`, I want to run a for-loop and collect the data from the form where the name is given as `translated-{{sentence.id}}`. However, I am not able to make the POST request handler that can directly collect the data from the form and save it in the `Sentence` model based on the `id` of the sentence. I need help in writing that request handler in my views.

Comment: What you describe is the exact use case for [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/). Try using them instead of multiple forms, then `UpdateView` will be able to handle it almost properly by default, without rewriting a bunch of methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this which doesn't use the `forms.py` at all. This is what the post request handler would look like.

```py
    # Handle the post request
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Get the project details from the database
        all_sentence_data = Sentence.objects.filter(project_id=pk)
        sentence_ids = [sentence.id for sentence in all_sentence_data]

        # Iterate through all the input fields in the form 
        for i in range(len(sentence_ids)): 
            
            # Get the translated text from the form
            try: 
                translated_text = request.POST[f"translated-{str(sentence_ids[i])}"]

                if translated_text: 
                    
                    # Update the Sentence object with the translated text
                    Sentence.objects.filter(id=sentence_ids[i]).update(translated_sentence=translated_text)
            
            except: 
                continue

        messages.success(request, "Your translations have been saved successfully!")
        return redirect('/translation/' + str(pk)+'/')
    
    else: 
        return redirect('/translation/' + str(pk)+'/')
```